# How to "group" (categorize) the Pages together?

Tags: categories, custom-field, pages, taxonomy, tags

I have a lot of `Pages` which can be (need to be) grouped under a number of different Categories. ** Then the more important thing is, i need to control those pages (of different groups) programatically via `functions.php`.

Lets say, i would have:

- Page A (Categorized as: `Fruits`)
- Page B (Categorized as: `Vehicles`)
- Page C (Categorized as: `Vehicles`)
- Page D (Categorized as: `Fruits`)
- Page E (Categorized as: `Technology`)

Then from `functions.php`, there would be some logics, like:

- If Page is under `Fruits` Category, then `echo "This is related to Fruits.";`.
- If Page is under `Vehicles` Category, then `echo "This is related to Vehicles.";`.
- If Page is under `Technology` Category, then `echo "This is related to Technologies.";`.

I dont know this is about Taxonomy or Tagging or Custom Field or something. But:

- **What is the ideal way to do it please? *(Especially to be able to control from backend coding.)***

---

And again please **let me repeat, "Pages"**. *(Not about Posts or any other)*

Comment: Use posts with categories and tags or custom post types with custom taxonomies, it is the best way of doing what you are describing.

Comment: Thank you but I think my question is about `Pages`.

Comment: I know that your question is about pages, I just made a suggestion of data structure that can fit better the description of your issue.

Comment: @cybmeta I agree, if you *need* to categorize "pages" then you should create a [Custom Post Type](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type) and [Custom Taxonomy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy). The built-in Pages were not designed to have categories or be categorized. A Custom Post Type can be a page or a post or anything you want. [Read More about Post Types](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types). Another option is create a Parent Page called "Fruits" then make subpages, the parent page would act as a Category, though it truely isn't.

Answer (score 0):

You can use categories with pages by registering the category taxonomy for the page object type:

```
function categories_for_pages(){
    register_taxonomy_for_object_type( 'category', 'page' );
}
add_action( 'init', 'categories_for_pages' );
```

If you want to use a separate taxonomy for this, you can [register your own taxonomy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy) for pages.

Answer (score 0):

1. **First thing you need to do is to enable categories for pages, quite simple**:

   ```php
   function enable_categories_for_pages() {
       register_taxonomy_for_object_type('category', 'page');  
   }
   add_action( 'init', 'enable_categories_for_pages' );
   ```

> **Note that in WordPress, categories are shared between different post types**

2. **To register the categories in advance**:

   ```php
   $wp_insert_category(array(
       'cat_name' => 'Fruit',
       'category_description' => 'My Fruit posts',
       'category_nicename' => 'Fruit'
   ));
   ```
3. **You can add categories to posts programmatically**:

   ```php
   wp_set_post_categories($post->ID, get_cat_ID( 'Fruit' ));
   ```
4. **When displaying the page** (named in Wordpress $post):

   ```php
   if ($post->post_type == 'page'){
       if (has_category( 'Fruits', $post)){
           echo "This is related to Fruits.";
       }
   }
   ```